# Is it possible to downgrade gcc 4.6.1 to 4.4.x?

Tags: 11.10, gcc

I've tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
```

But this does not work, running `gcc --version` gives a 'No such file or directory' error.

Comment: Note: I have found some [promising looking instructions](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2011/06/install-specific-version-gcc-ubuntu/), I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: This method does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install both gcc-4.4 and gcc-4.6 if you wish. The binaries for them would be: `/usr/bin/gcc-4.4` and `/usr/bin/gcc-4.6`.

Besides this, if you want `/usr/bin/gcc` to point to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.4`, then you have to update the link yourself or use `update-alternatives` as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7832892/183066).

Comment: @mac It's a shame the old link doesn't work anymore. I've updated the response to point to link you suggested since it provides a good explanation of what has to be done indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **No**

If you wish to use 4.4 for compiling tasks then install it, it's in the repos

The easiest way is to install **synaptic**, search gcc, g++, cpp.

You can also use the software centre, search gcc-, g++=, cpp= (note that = is not a typo)

Comment: How do I get it from the repos?

Comment: easiest is to install synaptic, search gcc, g++, cpp. I guess one could use software center though it's still a pain to use. In S-C I'd search gcc-, g++=, cpp= (note that = is not a typo